# Iptable l7-filter installation guide and block p2p

Tags: debian, iptables, firewall

I would install l7-filter to block P2P torrent,
First of all , I have a linux debian. I installed by the below command

```
apt-get install l7-filter-userspace
```

And then run command

```
iptables -I FORWARD -m layer7 --l7proto bittorrent -j DROP
```

but face with the error:

> iptables v1.4.14: Couldn't load match `layer7':No such file or
>   directory
>
> Try `iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information.

I really don't know what extra should I do ?

Answer (score 1):

To use L7, read the 2 links below:

**Option 1** - you will still need to load some kernel modules
http://kuscsik.blogspot.com/2008/02/how-to-userspace-l7-filter-on-ubuntu.html

**Option 2** - you will need to recompile the the kernel
http://www.ph-lwug.org/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=71:turn-your-linux-into-layer-7-filtering-appliance-l7-filter

Comment: second link is dead